# Returning the head pointer of a linked list

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

Why is this code giving right answer?
I am returning a pointer.But there is no segmentation fault in returning this.What is the complete mechanism of this Code?
Can anyone tell how the `input()` function is working and how its returning the head of linked-list?

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
typedef struct a{
int data;
struct a* next;
}link;
typedef link *node;

//Function to take input of linked list//

node input()
{
    int n,i;
    cout<<"Enter the size of the linked list\t";
    cin>>n;
    node g,header,rear;
    cout<<"Enter the elements\n";
    g=new link;
    g->next=NULL;
    cin>>g->data;
    header=g;
    rear=g;
    for(i=1;i<n;i++)
    {
        g=new link;
        cin>>g->data;
        g->next=NULL;
        rear->next=g;
        rear=g;
    }
    return header;
}

void output(node f)
{
    cout<<"Linked List ELEMENTS\n";
    //cout<<"\nThe content of linked list is\n";
    while(f!=NULL)
    {
        cout<<f->data<<"\t";
        f=f->next;
    }
}
int main()
{
node head,f;
head=input();
output(head);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you write this program yourself?

Comment: Why would there be a segmentation fault? Returning a pointer from a function is only a problem if you're returning a pointer to a local variable. `header` is a pointer to the head of the list, which was dynamically allocated using `new`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not mandatory to get segmentation fault every time pointer is returned. Segmentation fault happens when unallocated pointer is accessed. But the function first dynamically allocates the pointer using `new` and then accesses and returns it. So it works correctly.

`input()` function

1. size of linked list (user input)

   ```
   int n,i;
   cout<<"Enter the size of the linked list\t";
   cin>>n;
   ```
2. first element of the list in head node (user input)

   ```
   node g,header,rear;
   cout<<"Enter the elements\n";
   g=new link;
   g->next=NULL;
   cin>>g->data;
   header=g;
   rear=g;
   ```
3. subsequent elements of list connected to head node

   ```
   for(i=1;i<n;i++)
   {
       g=new link;
       cin>>g->data;
       g->next=NULL;
       rear->next=g;
       rear=g;
   }
   ```
4. head node returned

   ```
   return header;
   ```